# Comparing two models and finding the model with highest R squared

Tags: python

I have a loop that does automated regressions for two endogenous (dependent variables): income and log of income. My code creates 60 regression models: 30 for 10 provinces and 3 education levels for income and 30 for 10 provinces and 3 education levels for log of income.

I need to compare first 30 models (ones with income) with the second batch of 30 models (ones with log of income) to identify the highest R squared for each model. At the end, I need to have 30 models to keep at the end of the loop based on the highest Rsquared value..

Currently, my code created 60 models and I have not been able to find a way to insert another loop to identify the highest Rsquared. Here is my code:

```
modeles = []
for var_dep in [vardep1, vardep2]:
    for une_prov in dict_merged.values():
        continuer = True
        var_indep = []
        var_indep.append("cons")
        var_indep.append("ecage26")
        var_indep.append("ecage262")
        while continuer == True: 
            ma_reg = sm.OLS(une_educ[var_dep], une_educ[var_indep])
            mes_resultats = ma_reg.fit()    
            une_var_non_sig = False
            for une_var in var_indep: 
                if mes_resultats.pvalues[une_var] > 0.05:
                    une_var_non_sig = True
            if une_var_non_sig == True:
                variable_problematique = mes_resultats.pvalues.loc[mes_resultats.pvalues == mes_resultats.pvalues.max()].index[0]
                print("Je retire la variable: " + variable_problematique)
                index_drop = var_indep.index(variable_problematique)
                var_indep.pop(index_drop)
                if len(var_indep) == 0:
                    continuer = False
                    print("Notre technique prédit aucune variable. Misère!")
            else:
                continuer = False
        modeles.append(mes_resultats)
        print(mes_resultats.summary())
```

I wrote this code to keep Rsquared values in a list but it keeps the Rsquared values of all my 60 models. So, I cannot compare first 30 with the second batch of 30:

```
for var_dep in [vardep1, vardep2]:
    r_squared = []
    for un_modele in modeles:
       r_squared.append(un_modele.rsquared)
```

Comment: Where in your code is the list of R squared values from which you want to find the highest? Or where is any R squared value?

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question with the information on how I keep RSquared values for all models. My problem is that I need to compare models with each dependent variables and currently, my code does not do that.

Comment: Why do you not create two lists of R squared values instead? One for the first 30 models and one for the second 30 models?

Comment: That is what I am trying to do but I have not been successful. I want my loop to compare models and keep only 30 of them based on highest Rsquared. I tried creating two lists outside of my loop, a list for the first dependent variable and a second list for the second dependent variable. But since it is outside of the loop, it does not allow me to choose and keep the models with highest Rsquared in memory. It just allows me to see which Rsquared values are higher. And after that, I was stuck there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have this:

> ```
> modeles = []
> for var_dep in [vardep1, vardep2]:
>     for une_prov in dict_merged.values():
>         # ...
>         modeles.append(mes_resultats)
> ```

then `modeles` contains all 60 models and you can't distinguish between the models related to `vardep1` and the models related to `vardep2`.

You should create two lists of models instead, which are contained in another list to hold them:

```
all_models = []
for var_dep in [vardep1, vardep2]:
    modeles = []
    for une_prov in dict_merged.values():
        # ...
        modeles.append(mes_resultats)
    all_models.append(modeles)
```

Now `all_models[0]` will be a list of models corresponding to `vardep1` and `all_models[1]` accordingly for `vardep2`.

Similarly, if you have

> ```
> for var_dep in [vardep1, vardep2]:
>     r_squared = []
>     for un_modele in modeles:
>        r_squared.append(un_modele.rsquared)
> ```

you create two separate lists `r_squared` for `vardep1` and for `vardep2`, however after you are done with `vardep1` you discard the first list and overwrite the `r_squared` variable with a new empty list.

You need to keep the first list. The best way to do this is again to create another list which contains the two `r_squared` lists. In order to get the corresponding list of models for each `vardep1` and `vardep2`, you can use the `zip` function to iterate the `all_models` list and the list `[vardep1, vardep2]` in pairs:

```
r_squared_lists = []
for modeles, var_dep in zip(all_models, [vardep1, vardep2]):
    r_squared = []
    for un_modele in modeles:
       r_squared.append(un_modele.rsquared)
    # now save r_squared
    r_squared_lists.append(r_squared)
```

Now `r_squared_lists[0]` is a list containing the values that correspond to `vardep1`, and `r_squared_lists[1]` accordingly for `vardep2`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! For some reason, the code you posted creates the same list with 60 regressions twice on my end. But following a similar logic, I found another way to separate the lists by actually separating the models themselves. It seems to be working so far.

Comment: Oh, I see, `modeles` contained all 60 models and you also need to create two separate models lists in the same way.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I did: two separate models lists, two separate Rsquared lists, a comparison to find the highest and one single list than contain 30 models with highest Rsquared values. Then, I used that list to keep the actual regression models that match Rsquared values in that final list.

Comment: @FarmeratSchruteFarms By the way, take a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)